# I'm not able to get files in req.files when I call the api in nodejs reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, multer

I'm sending array of files of image to NodeJs to upload them on AWS but I get no value only empty array of files when I console.log(req.files).

```
image: 
[
File {name: 'Faateh Uni - function now() { [native code] }', lastModified: 1647858683757, lastModifiedDate: Mon Mar 21 2022 15:31:23 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 12771, …},
File {name: 'Faateh Uni - function now() { [native code] }', lastModified: 1647858683766, lastModifiedDate: Mon Mar 21 2022 15:31:23 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 411301, …},
File {name: 'Faateh Uni - function now() { [native code] }', lastModified: 1647858683769, lastModifiedDate: Mon Mar 21 2022 15:31:23 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 36455, …}

]
```

This is how i created these files :

```
for (let index in contentImages) {
      const contentImage = await fetch(contentImages[index]);
      const contentImageBlob = await contentImage.blob();
      const coverFile = new File(
        [contentImageBlob],
        `${submitValues.sourceName} - ${Date.now}`,
        { type: contentImageBlob.type }
      );
      image.push(coverFile);
    }
```

This is nodejs:

```
app.post(
        "/api/readingsources/new",
        upload.array("image", 5),
      
        (req, res) => {
            const coverImage = req;
            res.status(200).send("OK");
        }
    );
```